# How can I know an App is running under debug model in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio, I can click "Run" button in IDE to run an app, the app is running under debug model, but how can I know there is a debug model programatically? just like the following code.

```
If (IsDebug()){
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is in debug, it will diplay some prompt information",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else{
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is release edition, it will not diplay debug information",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: `if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
  // do something for a debug build
}`

Answer (score 2):

For simplicity, you can use `BuildConfig` such as `if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {...}`.

`BuildConfig` is generated in compile time when you click 'Run' in AndroidStudio, which looks like:

```
public final class BuildConfig {
  public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
  public static final String APPLICATION_ID = "YOUR APP";
  public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "debug";
  public static final String FLAVOR = "";
  public static final int VERSION_CODE = 1;
  public static final String VERSION_NAME = "YOUR VERSION";
}
```

But some bugs are reported if you're using this in your library project.
http://www.digipom.com/be-careful-with-buildconfig-debug/

If you want a more advanced way, you can define in your `build.gradle`.
*Enhancing your BuildConfig* in
http://toastdroid.com/2014/03/28/customizing-your-build-with-gradle/

Comment: Thanks!  Do you think that Altoyr's way is always OK ?

Comment: @HelloCw yes, if you need to customize your own flag, that's a good example. But if you want to use this in library project, you may need some other workaround because there is a bug of `android gradle plugin` mentioned in my reply.

Comment: Thanks, do you mean that I maybe also meet bugs even if I use Altoyr's code?

Comment: Do you mean that I also maybe meet bugs even if I use Altoyr's code?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to add BuildConfig-Variables to the Gradle-script and read them in the Code.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        ...
        buildConfigField "int", "appMode", "0"
    }

    debug {
        ...
        buildConfigField "int", "appMode", "1"
    }
}
```

Read the variable like this:

```
If (BuildConfig.appMode == 1){
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is in debug, it will diplay some prompt information",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else{
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is release edition, it will not diplay debug information",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to check if the app is debuggable or not

```
private boolean isDebuggable(Context ctx)
{
    boolean debuggable = false;

    PackageManager pm = ctx.getPackageManager();
    try
    {
        ApplicationInfo appinfo = pm.getApplicationInfo(ctx.getPackageName(), 0);
        debuggable = (0 != (appinfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE));
    }
    catch(NameNotFoundException e)
    {
        /*debuggable variable will remain false*/
    }

    return debuggable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
boolean isDebuggable =  ( 0 != ( getApplicationInfo().flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE ) );
```